# Api call- Translate Python Post to R

Tags: python, r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently trying to translate this API call over from R to python. I have seen many of these sort of questions on the forum but still can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the request that works in python:

```py
import requests

rest_endpoint = "some url"
response = requests.post ( rest_endpoint , 
                           headers = auth_header , 
                           json = { 'ExperimentName' : 'experiment_name' ,
                                    'ParameterAssignments' : { 'input_path' : 'this_is_a_test2.csv' } } )
```

I greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Using the `httr` package, the syntax would be like this:

```r
library(httr)

rest_endpoint <- "https://httpbin.org/post"
msg <- "{ 'ExperimentName' : 'experiment_name' ,
          'ParameterAssignments' : { 'input_path' : 'this_is_a_test2.csv' } }"

POST(rest_endpoint, 
     authenticate('user', 'password'),
     body = msg, 
     encode = 'raw')
#> Response [https://httpbin.org/post]
#>   Date: 2022-04-01 14:03
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: application/json
#>   Size: 632 B
#> {
#>   "args": {}, 
#>   "data": "{ 'ExperimentName' : 'experiment_name' ,\n          'ParameterAssi...
#>   "files": {}, 
#>   "form": {}, 
#>   "headers": {
#>     "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
#>     "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip", 
#>     "Authorization": "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==", 
#>     "Content-Length": "118", 
#> ...
```

An alternative method, which may work for you depending on how your data is formatted, would be:

```r
rest_endpoint <- "https://httpbin.org/post"
msg <- list(ExperimentName = 'experiment_name',
            ParameterAssignments = list(input_path = 'this_is_a_test2.csv'))

POST(rest_endpoint, 
     authenticate('user', 'password'),
     body = msg, 
     encode = 'json')
```

which gives essentially the same result.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Appreciate the response. Quick question on this. Let's say the header portion of what I have above in python is a bearer token. How would that change the authenticate portion?- Sorry if it's an obvious question. This is my first time doing something like this.

Comment: @tfr950 Instead of using `authenticate('user', 'password')` you could try `add_headers(Authenticate = paste('Bearer', my_token))` . Difficult to debug without a concrete example though.